# Search algorithm for DICOM files c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, search-engine, dicom

I'm currently working with DICOM files and want to perform a search on the files. My search is attribute based, i.e for example if i enter patient name= John, age=30, it should search for that particular file which satisfies both conditions. Please help me out as to which search algorithm i could use. I have looked at BOOST, but i'm not sure if that's the way out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ClearCanvas](http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/) and do a search across the DICOM metadata embedded in the file.

Comment: Hi, i need to write a code in c#, not exactly use a software available. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: ClearCanvas is open source and written in C#.  It's no more "software available" than someone from SO providing your solution for you.

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this.will look into it. Thanku

Comment: As mentioned, there's a Study Filters mechanism in ClearCanvas Workstation that does what you're attempting to do.  It allows searching by virtually any DICOM tag.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me the link to the opensource code? ALso, can ClearCanvas be used to create my own UI? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In [Evil Dicom](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com) :

```
List<string> found = new List<string>();

    foreach(string path in possiblePaths){
        DicomFile df =new DicomFile(path);
        if(df.PATIENT_NAME.Data=="John" && df.PATIENT_AGE.Data=="30Y"){
           found.Add(path);
        }
    }
```